# Face Recognition

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All
I just tried the new face recognition package but when i run Fserver i get the following error

```
[ INFO] [1325746855.901582077]: Could not load Haar cascade Face detection classifier in 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'.
```

I am using Ubuntu 10.4 32 bit and ros electric with vision opencv installed from debs

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12528/face-recognition/) by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 215 on 2012-01-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-01-04**:
Please post more information.  There is not enough information here to reproduce your effrots.  See http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Fserver requires haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml to be in the same directory as you run the Fserver.
The file was missing in the package, but now It has been uploaded in the repository in the face_recognition directory.

Cheers,
Pouyan

---

Originally posted by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) with karma: 143 on 2012-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-05**:
No problem, I was just recommending a more general solution in a future release.

**Comment by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) on 2012-01-05**:
Jog, Thanks for your comments, will consider that for the future, but for now cmd works.

**Comment by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) on 2012-01-05**:
When you use cmd="node", the working directory is face_recognition/bin. If you put the files in the bin directory, should be no problem.

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2012-01-05**:
I just tried it and i cant get it to work it shows a error when i use the directory if i use node or ROS_HOME  and put the file in those locations i get the file not found error

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-05**:
That is really not the recommended way to use `roslaunch`. I am not even sure it works. Have you tried it?

**Comment by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) on 2012-01-05**:
As mentioned above,  the program searches for its input files in its working directory which is not necessarily the package directory. In 'roslaunch', you can set the working directory using 'cwd' attribute to point to the directory in which necessary input files are placed.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-05**:
Depending on the current directory being the package directory is very unfriendly for people using `roslaunch`. Perhaps a future release might provide a more flexible access mechanism?

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2012-01-05**:
Running from the installation  directory was the key the server started and i was able to acquire a face  Thanks

**Comment by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) on 2012-01-05**:
You might also wish to put the data folder (containing sample pictures) and the train.txt file(which list the training examples) in the same directory. As all these are in the face_recognition directory by default, simply try : 1-roscd face_recognition 2-rosrun face_recognition Fserver

**Comment by [Pouyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1471/pouyan/) on 2012-01-05**:
rosmake in not necessary again. you should just run the Fserver from the directory in which haarcascade_frontface_alt.xml is placed. For example : 1- copy haarcascade_frontface_alt.xml to /home/new_dir 2-cd /home/new_dir 3-rosrun face_recognition Fserver.   Let me know if it works :)

**Comment by [Peter Heim](https://answers.ros.org/users/71/peter-heim/) on 2012-01-05**:
Hi
Just updated and did a rosmake the new files is in the face_recognition directory but i still get the same error